# Spacemacs Clojure Cider Debugger Gives Error, "No reader function for tag dbg"

Tags: spacemacs, cider

After connecting Cider to Spacemacs, when trying to set a debug breakpoint on a function using `,-d-b` (`cider-debug-defun-at-point`), I see the following message in the `*cider-error*` buffer.

```
3. Unhandled clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo

2. Caused by clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException

1. Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
   No reader function for tag dbg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using boot, from the Cider REPL, run this code:
`(boot.core/load-data-readers!)`

See this GitHub issue for details: https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1596

I don't know if this issue happens if you're using leiningen.